# Headstart for extjs6 and CMD

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I would just like to display a panel on my browse. I know how to do with extjs4 but how to do with extjs6 and sencha CMD.I am able to install CMD and generate an universal app with it, but i am not knowing how to proceed further. I am confused with the app.js and app.json files. what changes to be made on app.js or is there any other js file i should change? please give me a head start.

Comment: Recommend reading http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/getting_started/login_app.html

Comment: Pro tipp: Generate a classic app and copy all your source over from  the ExtJS 4 version. In such an easy example, everything should run fine then. (It took me three weeks already to get everything running again in our more sophisticated app, mostly because they completely changed the way grids are rendered...)